# new line appending on my encrypted string

Tags: java, encryption, base64

In Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    System.out.println("encrypt:" + encryptPassword("superuser")+":" );
}

public static String encryptPassword(final String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] hashPassword = md.digest(password.getBytes());
    String encryPass = Base64.encodeBase64String(hashPassword);
    return encryPass;
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
encrypt:C66i8K4gFQ23j1jN2sRCqQ==:
```

But when I implemented the same thing in my application I'm getting the output below:

```
encrypt:C66i8K4gFQ23j1jN2sRCqQ==
:
```

**Note:** new line appending on my encrypted string.

application code:

```
public boolean authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal(UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials) {
    try {
        System.out.println("encrypt:" + getHash("superuser")+":" );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new BadCredentialsAuthenticationException(ErrorConstants.CONNECTION_FAILED);
    }
}

private String getHash(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{  
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] hashPassword = md.digest(password.getBytes());
    String encryPass = Base64.encodeBase64String(hashPassword);
    return encryPass;
}
```

How I can remove that extra new line.
why this is happened, please help me **what is the reason?**

Comment: Where is your new line space?

Comment: what extra new line space?? can you please be clear

Comment: Just do encyPass.replaceAll("\n","") it will be right

Comment: above "note" output i pasted my output but is coming as space

Comment: Please pay more attention to the formatting of your code. You appear not to have even pasted the full code - your authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal method doesn't have a closing brace. Also, use spaces rather than tabs in Stack Overflow.

Comment: i added

    String encryPass = Base64.encodeBase64String(hashPassword).trim();

i getting correct output. but i surprised, same code when i executed in main() method I'm getting correct answer,same thing i implemented in application I'm getting extra new line. why this is happened, please help me **what is the reason?**

Comment: The correct answer is [Dory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040539/new-line-appending-on-my-encrypted-string#25011746), not the accepted one.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

I may be late in answering this, but came across with same problem. Actually problem lies here
`Base64.encodeBase64String(hashPassword)`

Change that line to look like this it should work:
`Base64.encodeBase64String(hashPassword,Base64.NO_WRAP)`

By default the Android Base64 util adds a newline character to the end of the encoded string.
The Base64.NO_WRAP flag tells the util to create the encoded string without the newline character.

Check [here](http://lukieb.blogspot.in/2013/06/base64encodetostring-adds-newline.html)

Comment: welcome,trimming text would not get correct output always. It was not giving me,so try other options and found solution. :)

Comment: If you are late answering this, thank I pity everyone who had this problem before you answered it :D

Comment: Why on earth do newlines get inserted?

Comment: @ConorPatrick For old programs, not working with long lines. Legacy stuff. Imho no_wrap should be default by now and wrap should be an extra bit flag.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone needs this for any libraries using OkHttp, there's a `Credentials` class you can use for Base64 encoding your username/pass

```
String credentials = Credentials.basic("username", "password");

request.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, credentials);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
String encryPass = Base64.encodeBase64String(hashPassword).trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

**You just need to Use Base64 encoding in following way**

```
Base64.encodeBase64String("Your data to encrypt in base64", Base64.DEFAULT)
```

**Change above line with the followings**

```
Base64.encodeBase64String("Your data to encrypt in base64",Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

**It worked for me.**

Comment: `Base64.encodeBase64String("Your data to encrypt in base64",Base64.NO_WRAP)` is the accepted answer. not sure what different in you answer.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner option without trimming:

```
String encryPass = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(hashPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of `Base64.encodeBase64String()`. What is that method?

If it's from Apache commons, be aware that there are a few different classes that handle whitespace differently.

For example, [`org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5b%5d%29) chunks output, and it probably adds a CR-LF sequence to the final chunk.

The more common version, [`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29), does not add whitespace.

Comment: both places I'm using **org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64**

Comment: Can confirm that with `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` I'm also getting random trailing whitespace characters. (commons-codec-1.4.jar)

Comment: @radimpe: version 1.4 of that class changed the behavior of the default constructor to do chunking and appends a newline character. v1.3 or v1.5 would not do this. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CODEC-89

Comment: Luckily there's a well-specified and built-in core Java implementation finally (`java.util.Base64`).